# Strange behavior while listing directories in Jenkinsfile where docker is running as agent

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am running a very basic Jenkinsfile, docker as agent.
Below is the Jenkinsfile.

```
pipeline{
    agent none
    stages{
        stage('Tomcat version'){
            agent{
                docker {image 'tomcat:jre21-temurin'}
            }
            steps{
                // below ls command showing directories inside the container 
                sh 'ls /usr/local'

                //but below ls and pwd command showing directories present in cuurrent jenkins workspace 
                sh 'ls'
                sh 'pwd'

                //this command runs inside container
                sh 'cat /usr/local/tomcat/RELEASE-NOTES | grep "Apache Tomcat Version"'

                // This command also runs inside container
                sh 'ls /usr/local'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In above Jenkinsfile I am seeing very strange behavior as I have explained in every step.

Can someone please helm me to understand, what exactly happening here?

Comment: I'd suggest asking this on https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins uses a Docker [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) to inject the workspace directory into the container.  That lets you see the `java` and Tomcat that are preinstalled in the image in places like `/usr/local`, but the workspace directory (`/var/lib/jenkins/...`?) will be in the same place and have the same contents in both container and non-container build steps.

This means you can use a container to get build tools, but otherwise run what looks like a normal-looking build.

```groovy
stage('Build application') {
  agent {
    docker {
      image 'eclipse-temurin:17-jdk'
    }
  }
  steps {
    // This is the exact same build step you'd run without Docker
    // in the exact same directory
    sh './gradlew build'
  }
}
```

Comment: That means, Jenkins will clone git repo in jenkins workspace and bind it to docker container and once pipeline execution is done it will remove bind mounts. But git repo will still be present in jenkins workspace.

Comment: Assuming the pipeline has previously checked out the repository, that's essentially correct.